# Download multiple files using "download.file" function

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to download PDFs from a website using R.

I have a vector of the PDF-URLs (*pdfurls*) and a vector of destination file names (*destinations*):

e.g.:

```
pdfurls <- c("http://website/name1.pdf", "http://website/name2.pdf")
destinations <- c("C:/username/name1.pdf", "C:/username/name2.pdf")
```

The code I am using is:

```
for(i in 1:length(urls)){
    download.file(urls, destinations, mode="wb")}
```

However, when I run the code, R accesses the URL, downloads the first PDF, and repeats downloading the same PDF over and over again.

I have read this post: [for loop on R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625377/for-loop-on-r-function) and was wondering if this has something to do with the function itself or is there a problem with my loop?

The code is similar to the post here: [How to download multiple files using loop in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241713/how-to-download-multiple-files-using-loop-in-r) so I was wondering why it is not working and if there is a better way to download multiple files using R.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your loop is mostly fine, except you forgot to index the `urls` and `destinations` objects.

Tangentially, I would recommend getting in the habit of using `seq_along` instead of `1:length()` when defining `for` loops.

```
for(i in seq_along(urls)){
    download.file(urls[i], destinations[i], mode="wb")
}
```

---

Or using *Map* as suggested by [@docendodiscimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus) :

```
Map(function(u, d) download.file(u, d, mode="wb"), urls, destinations)
```