# Downloading multiple files in R with variable length, nested URLs

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, concatenation

New member here. Trying to download a large number of files from a website in R (but open to suggestions as well, such as wget.)

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246739/downloading-multiple-files-using-download-file-function-in-r), I understand I must create a vector with the desired URLs. My initial problem is to write this vector, since I have 27 states and 34 agencies within each state. I must download one file for each agency for all states. Whereas the state codes are always two characters, the agency codes are 2 to 7 characters long. The URLs would look like this:

```
http://website.gov/xx_yyyyyyy.zip
```

where `xx`is the state code and `yyyyyyy` the agency code, between 2 and 7 characters long. I am lost as to how to build one such loop.

I assume I can then download this url list with the following function:

```
for(i in 1:length(url)){
download.file(urls, destinations, mode="wb")}
```

Does that make sense?

(Disclaimer: an earlier version of this post was uploaded earlier but incomplete. My mistake, sorry!)

Comment: This simple example may help `paste0(rep(letters[1:4], 4), rep(1:4, each=4))`. Without more information as to the names of the agencies, it will not be possible to say much more.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Agency names are acronyms: FAA, DEA, NTSB, and such. I've created a vector `agency` with these acronyms, as well as a `states` vector with the 27 states I need. Will try your suggestion and post back.

Comment: Thanks, @Imo! Your input helped me a lot. Now I understand the dynamics of adding string variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will download them in batches and take advantage of the speedier simultaneous downloading capabilities of `download.file()` if the `libcurl` option is available on your installation of R:

```
library(purrr)

states <- state.abb[1:27]
agencies <- c("AID", "AMBC", "AMTRAK", "APHIS", "ATF", "BBG", "DOJ", "DOT",
              "BIA", "BLM", "BOP", "CBFO", "CBP", "CCR", "CEQ", "CFTC", "CIA",
              "CIS", "CMS", "CNS", "CO", "CPSC", "CRIM", "CRT", "CSB", "CSOSA",
              "DA", "DEA", "DHS", "DIA", "DNFSB", "DOC", "DOD", "DOE", "DOI")

walk(states, function(x) {
   map(x, ~sprintf("http://website.gov/%s_%s.zip", ., agencies)) %>% 
    flatten_chr() -> urls
    download.file(urls, basename(urls), method="libcurl")
})
```

Comment: That is a very elegant solution, @hrbrmstr. Thanks for the input. I will test it and post back.

Comment: Your script worked flawlessly -- and was the fastest download I've ever seen. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
agency <- c("FAA", "DEA", "NTSB")
states <- c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR")

URLs <-
paste0("http://website.gov/",
       rep(agency, length(agency)),
       "_",
       rep(states, length(states)),
       ".zip")
```

Then loop through the `URLs` vector to pull the zip files. It will be faster if you use an apply function.

Comment: this works, but only because the lengths of agency and states are relatively prime. To make it more general, one of the rep commands should specify `each`, and the other should specify `times`. Will `apply` really make it faster in this case?

Comment: Thanks, @epo3. It worked perfectly. Now I suppose I can use `download.file()` and just cycle through all urls. Thanks again!

Comment: @Miff: I suppose I need to specify each state one `time` and `each` agency 27 times?

Comment: @questionMarc `paste0("http://website.gov/", rep(agency, each=length(agency)), "_",      rep(states, times=length(states)), ".zip")`

Comment: Excellent, @Miff. Makes perfect sense, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If all your agency codes are the same within each state code you could use the below to create your vector of urls to loop through. (You will also need a vector of destinations the same size).

```
#Getting all combinations
States <- c("AA","BB")
Agency <- c("ABCDEFG","HIJKLMN")
AllCombinations <- expand.grid(States, Agency)
AllCombinationsVec <- paste0("http://website.gov/" ,AllCombinations$Var1, "_",AllCombinations$Var2,".zip" )
```

You can then try looping through each file something like this:

```
#loop method

for(i in seq(AllCombinationsVec)){
  download.file(AllCombinationsVec[i], destinations[i], mode="wb")}
```

This is also another way of looping through items apply functions will apply a function to every item in a list or vector.

```
#lapply method

mapply(function(x, y) download.file(x,y, mode="wb"),x = AllCombinationsVec, y = destinations)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It has worked as well!