# Faster way to download multiple files in R

Tags: r, rcurl, r-download.file

I write a small downloader in R, in order to download some log files from remote server in one run:

```r
file_remote <- fun_to_list_URLs()
file_local <- fun_to_gen_local_paths()
credentials <- "usr/pwd"

downloader <- function(file_remote, file_local, credentials) {
  data_bin <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(
    file_remote,
    userpwd = credentials,
    ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,
    forbid.reuse = TRUE
  )
  
  writeBin(data_bin, file_local)
}
  
purrr::walk2(
  file_remote,
  file_local,
  ~ downloader(
    file_remote = .x,
    file_local = .y,
    credentials = credentials
  )
)
```

This works, but slowly, especially compare it to some FTP clients like WinSCP, downloading 64 log files, each 2kb, takes minutes.

Is there a faster way to download a lot of files in R?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185735/downloading-multiple-files-in-r-with-variable-length-nested-urls

Comment: @Quinten Seems that `download.file()` doesn't work with SFTP that needs credential.

Comment: @Quniten Got it. Use "sftp://usr:pwd@remoteserver.com/path"

Comment: Maybe it works here also like shown in [Parallel download using Curl command line utility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634109/10488504) using something like `parallel::mclapply` to speed it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `curl` package has a way to perform async requests, which means that downloads are performed simultaneously instead of one after another. Especially with smaller files this should give you a large boost in performance. Here is a barebone function that does that (**since version 5.0.0**, the `curl` package has **a native version** of this function also called `multi_download`):

```r
# total_con: max total concurrent connections.
# host_con: max concurrent connections per host.
# print: print status of requests at the end.
multi_download <- function(file_remote, 
                           file_local,
                           total_con = 1000L, 
                           host_con  = 1000L,
                           print = TRUE) {
  
  # check for duplication (deactivated for testing)
  # dups <- duplicated(file_remote) | duplicated(file_local)
  # file_remote <- file_remote[!dups]
  # file_local <- file_local[!dups]
  
  # create pool
  pool <- curl::new_pool(total_con = total_con,
                         host_con = host_con)
  
  # function performed on successful request
  save_download <- function(req) {
    writeBin(req$content, file_local[file_remote == req$url])
  }
  
  # setup async calls
  invisible(
    lapply(
      file_remote, function(f) 
        curl::curl_fetch_multi(f, done = save_download, pool = pool)
    )
  )
  
  # all created requests are performed here
  out <- curl::multi_run(pool = pool)
  
  if (print) print(out)
  
}
```

Now we need some test files to compare it to your baseline approach. I use covid data from the Johns Hopkins University GitHub page as it contains many small csv files which should be similar to your files.

```r
file_remote <- paste0(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/",
  format(seq(as.Date("2020-03-03"), as.Date("2022-06-01"), by = "day"), "%d-%m-%Y"),
  ".csv"
)
file_local <- paste0("/home/johannes/Downloads/test/", seq_along(file_remote), ".bin")
```

We could also infer the file names from the URLs but I assume that is not what you want. So now lets compare the approaches for these 821 files:

```r
res <- bench::mark(
  baseline(),
  multi_download(file_remote, 
                 file_local,
                 print = FALSE),
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
summary(res)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                                                min median `itr/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                                             <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl>
#> 1 baseline()                                               2.8m   2.8m   0.00595
#> 2 multi_download(file_remote, file_local, print = FALSE)  12.7s  12.7s   0.0789 
#> # … with 2 more variables: mem_alloc <bch:byt>, `gc/sec` <dbl>
summary(res, relative = TRUE)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                                               min median `itr/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                                             <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 baseline()                                              13.3   13.3       1  
#> 2 multi_download(file_remote, file_local, print = FALSE)   1      1        13.3
#> # … with 2 more variables: mem_alloc <dbl>, `gc/sec` <dbl>
```

The new approach is 13.3 times faster than the original one. I would assume that the difference will be bigger the more files you have. Note though, that this benchmark is not perfect as my internet speed fluctuates quite a bit.

The function should also be improved in terms of handling errors (currently you get a message how many requests have been successful and how many errored, but no indication which files exist). My understanding is also that `multi_run` writes files to the memory before `save_download` writes them to disk. With small files this is fine, but it might be an issue with larger ones.

#### baseline function

```r
baseline <- function() {
  credentials <- "usr/pwd"
  downloader <- function(file_remote, file_local, credentials) {
    data_bin <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(
      file_remote,
      userpwd = credentials,
      ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,
      forbid.reuse = TRUE
    )
    writeBin(data_bin, file_local)
  }
  
  purrr::walk2(
    file_remote,
    file_local,
    ~ downloader(
      file_remote = .x,
      file_local = .y,
      credentials = credentials
    )
  )
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>