# for loop and downloads with multiple urls

Tags: r, url, download

Hi I was referring to the question here - [Downloading multiple files using "download.file" function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246739/downloading-multiple-files-using-download-file-function-in-r/42093739?noredirect=1#comment71358040_42093739)

But I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I want to download data from multiple urls and I am using the following code:

I am trying to do something similar and am relatively new at R. Below is my code:

```
temp <- tempfile(pattern = "my", fileext = ".txt")    #my is a vector in YYMM form

masterfile = as.data.frame(NULL)

for(i in 1:length(my)) {

  download.file(url = paste0("http://www2.census.gov/econ/bps/Metro/ma", "my[i]", "c.txt"), destfile = paste0("/Users/shashankrai/GitHub/data-science/homeworks/homework1/","my[i]","c.txt"), mode = wb)

temp <- read.table(paste0("/Users/shashankrai/GitHub/data-science/homeworks/homework1/","my[i]","c.txt"), sep = ",", skip = 3)[, c(1,3,5)]

masterfile <- rbind(masterfile, temp)

}
```

It throws up the following error:

> curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 44
>
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition:  Warning messages:
>
> 1: In download.file(url =
>   paste0("http://www2.census.gov/econ/bps/Metro/ma",  :   download had
>   nonzero exit status
>
> 2: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   '/Users/shashankrai/GitHub/data-science/homeworks/homework1/my[i]c.txt':
>   No such file or directory

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have also tried this:

```
temp <- tempfile(pattern = "my", fileext = ".txt")

masterfile = as.data.frame(NULL)

for(i in 1:length(my)) {

  download.file(url = paste0("url", "my[i]", "c.txt"), destfile = my[i], mode = wb)

  temp <- read.table(my[i], sep = ",", skip = 3)[, c(1,3,5)]

  masterfile <- rbind(masterfile, temp)

}
```

Comment: `"my[i]"` should be `my[i]`

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yeah, I noticed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Figured it out. This is a code that finally worked:

```
masterfile = as.data.frame(NULL)

for(i in 1:length(my)) {

  temp <- tempfile(pattern = "my", fileext = ".txt")

  download.file(url = paste0("http://www2.census.gov/econ/bps/Metro/ma",     my[i], "c.txt"), destfile = temp[i], mode = wb)

  masterfile <- rbind(masterfile, read.table(file = temp[i], sep = ",", skip = 3)[, c(1,3,5)])

}
```